# haproxy compression and chunked encoding

Tags: compression, gzip, haproxy

We detected a very strange bug in haproxy 1.7.9 today, that we are using from a Centos Build:

When we add the `compression` keyword and the transfer is `chunked` because of the size of the file, no matter if we `Accept-Encoding: gzip` (or whatever), or not, the haproxy does not finish the transfer correctly but hangs forever.

Removing all `compression` keyword lines from the haproxy configuration works perfectly though, because the backend application server already parses the `Accept-Encoding` header for compression algorithms and compresses the content itself.

I would thus mark the `compression` keyword in haproxy as **dangerous**. This situation is very hard to debug and its even harder to figure out, why haproxy behaves that bad!

1. Is there any version where this bug is removed?
2. Why does this even happen with `compression algo identity`?
3. Why does this happen, though compression should be turned off for chunked transfers?
4. Why does this happens though the mime-type is not within the `compression type` set of mime-types?

(Bonus Question: How can any professional live with such bad situations?)

TERMINAL OUTPUT FROM THE TESTS:

```
admin@bastion1$ time curl -v -k -o/dev/null -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" 'http://IP/URLto/deps.js'
* About to connect() to XXX port 80 (#0)
*   Trying XXX...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to XXX (XXX) port 80 (#0)
> GET /URLto/deps.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: XXX
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: close
< Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 15:14:29 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 19:28:26 GMT
< ETag: "3bfdf549feec78af317650f9c35a7687"
< Content-Type: application/javascript
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
{ [data not shown]
100 15136    0 15136    0     0    247      0 --:--:--  0:01:01 --:--:--     0^C
```

ends in a timeout, with or without `Accept-Encoding: gzip` and this also happens if of if not `compression type` is `application/javascript` or just something else and even with `compression offload`.

Removing all `compression` keywords in the haproxy sections enables the application server to do its compression on its own and delivers the data as requested by `Accept-Encoding`:

```
admin@bastion1$ time curl -v -k -o/dev/null -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" 'http://.../deps.js' [...]
> GET .../deps.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: close
< Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 15:20:40 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 19:28:26 GMT
< ETag: "3bfdf549feec78af317650f9c35a7687--gzip"
< Content-Type: application/javascript
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Encoding: gzip
<
{ [data not shown]
100  596k    0  596k    0     0  5523k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5574k
* Closing connection 0

real    0m0.112s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.002s
```

without compression

```
admin@bastion1$ time curl -v -k -o/dev/null 'http://.../deps.js'
[...]
> GET .../deps.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: close
< Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 15:26:05 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 19:28:26 GMT
< ETag: "3bfdf549feec78af317650f9c35a7687"
< Content-Type: application/javascript
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
{ [data not shown]
100 1592k    0 1592k    0     0  52.2M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53.6M
* Closing connection 0

real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Comment: BTW: Please don't answer: Why you are not using an up-to-date version of haproxy, or similar. If you know this problem and if you know a version where this is solved, you can give me a version hint (best with links to the bugfix), otherwise please just answer one or more of my questions.

Comment: This only happens to big transfers (plain size ~1.5M, compressed ~600k)